# Find $x$, $y$, $z$ maximum and minimum points of ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have a rotated ellipsoid of form
$$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2hxy + 2gxz+2fyz -1 = 0$$
And I want to calculate the maximum and minimum values of $x$, $y$ and $z$.

As the ellipsoid is centered in the origin of my reference system, I can assume the absolute values of the minimum values are the maximum values. I know how to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the ellipsoid, yet it doesn't help me. If the ellipsoid was not rotated things would be easier. As it is, or can be, rotated, $3$ variables come into place.

My guess is it's not that difficult, but I don't see the solution. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $M_{3\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$, the space of $3 \times 1$ column vectors, by following map:

$$\mathbb{R}^3 \ni (x,y,z)\quad \longleftrightarrow\quad p = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} \in M_{3\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$$

Let $A \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ be the $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & h & g\\ h & b & f \\ g & f & c\end{bmatrix}$$
In terms of them, the equation of the ellipsoid becomes

$$p^T A p = 1$$
For a point $p$ on this ellipsoid, its normal is in the direction of $\nabla( p^T A p ) \propto A p$.
On the point where $x$ is maximized, this normal vectors points toward the +ve x-direction (i.e. $e_1 = (1,0,0)$ ). This implies

$$A p = \lambda e_1 \quad\iff\quad p = \lambda A^{-1} e_1$$
for some real number $\lambda$. Since $p$ lies on the ellipsoid, we have

$$1 = p^T A p = \lambda^2 e_1^T A^{-1} e_1 \implies \lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ e_1^T A^{-1} e_1 }}$$
So the largest $x$ is

$$x_{max} = e_1 \cdot p =  \frac{ e_1^T A^{-1} e_1 }{\sqrt{e_1^T A e_1}}
= \sqrt{ e_1^T A^{-1} e_1} = \sqrt{(A^{-1})_{11}}$$

Similar things happens to the maximum value of $y$ and $z$. To compute the
values of $(x_{max}, y_{max}, z_{max})$, just compute the diagonal elements of
$A^{-1}$ and take square roots, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
(x_{max}, y_{max}, z_{max}) &= \left( \sqrt{(A^{-1})_{11}},
\sqrt{(A^{-1})_{22}}, \sqrt{(A^{-1})_{33}} \right)\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt{\det(A)}}\left(\sqrt{bc - f^2}, \sqrt{ac - g^2}, \sqrt{ab - h^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

**Notes**

It turns out I have answered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995438/59379) 5 years ago. No wonder I feel
déjà vu...

Comment: I belive I didn't find the post you've linked, my bad. The answer is exactly was I was looking for.