# Smallest box including an ellipse

Tags: geometry, optimization, conic-sections, symmetric-matrices

Let us consider an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the form
$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | x'Cx \le 1\}$, where $C$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

What is the smallest box $\prod_{i=1}^n [-a_i,a_i]$ the ellipsoid is a subset of?

Comment: For boxes aligned with coordinate axes, the smallest one is obtained by setting $a_i$ to $\sqrt{(C^{-1})_{ii}}$, the square root of the $i^{th}$ diagonal element of $C$'s inverse. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/995438/59379) for a proof. If the box need not be aligned with axes, the smallest box is the one who axes aligned with the principal axes of ellipsoid.

Comment: @achillehui In this case, the enclosing box is axis-aligned.

Comment: Thx! Quite easy indeed.